# Is an estimator that always have a value of zero is a linear estimator?

Tags: regression, estimators

Consider a simple linear regression model:
$$Y=\beta_0+\beta_1 X +u$$

Here, we can consider an estimator that does not use any data:
$$\hat{\beta}_1=0$$

That is, regardless of the observed data, the estimated value is always zero.

Then, we can write the estimator as a linear function of the observed dependent variable:
$$\hat{\beta}_1=\sum_i c_i y_i,$$

where $c_i=0$ for all $i=1,\ldots,N$.

Of course, this is a ridiculous estimator, but, by definition, we can say that $\hat{\beta}_1$ is a linear estimator.

I am pretty sure that this is true. But, I want to double check it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An estimator is a measurable function not dependant on the parameter. Any constant function is a legit estimator.

Any statistic which is a linear function of response, say $\boldsymbol\ell^\top\mathbf y, $ is a linear estimator.

If all the coefficients of $\boldsymbol\ell$ are $0, $ then the statistic is $0,$ as you noted.

But I am curious what the utility of such estimator is.

Rather more important in linear models is the class of *linear zero functions*, those $\boldsymbol\ell^\top\mathbf y$ such that $\mathbb E[\boldsymbol\ell^\top\mathbf y]=0, $ i.e. these are the linear unbiased estimators of zero. An estimable linear parametric function is BLUE (of its expectation) if and only if it is uncorrelated with every lzf.

Comment: That is very clear explanation. As you said, there is no utility of the estimator I imagined. I was just wondering if you could say that the $\hat{\beta}_1$ above is a linear estimator.

Comment: You expressed $\hat{\beta}_1$ as a linear function of responses. So, yes.